# Ejecutar trigger en SQL server 2008, error actualización/eliminacion

Tags: sql, trigger, sql-server-2008

tengo un trigger el cual se debería ejecutar al insertar un campo nuevo en la tabla Clientes y mandar por correo ese ultimo registro insertado en la tabla. El registro del nuevo cliente se hace desde otra aplicación de escritorio. Sin embargo al tratar de guardar los nuevos datos no lo hace y manda un error de actualización/Eliminación.

Si cambio la linea "AFTER INSERT" por un Update y solo actualizo el Cliente, si hace todo el proceso y el correo se envía, pero si lo dejo en Insert no lo hace. Intente también con un "IF UPDATE (codext)" que es un consecutivo de la tabla, el cual aumenta al dar de alta clientes. Estoy ocupando SQL server 2008.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Nuevo_Cliente]
ON [dbo].[Clientes] 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 
  DECLARE @den VARCHAR(60),
  @cod VARCHAR(10), 
  @rfc VARCHAR(20), 
  @fax VARCHAR(10), 
  @polcor VARCHAR (10),
  @debglo VARCHAR (10),
  @tableHTML NVARCHAR (MAX);
  IF UPDATE (codext) 
  BEGIN 
     SELECT @cod = cod, @den = den, 
            @rfc = rfc, @fax = fax, 
            @polcor = polcor, @debglo = debglo 
  FROM inserted 
  SET @tableHTML = 
  N'<H3>Cliente Nuevo </H3>' +
  N'<table>' +  
  N'<style>' +
  N'td, tr{border: solid black 1px; 
  padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; 
  padding-top:1px; padding-bottom:1px; 
  font-size:10pt; color:Black;}' +
  '</style>' +
   N'<tr><th>Codigo de Cliente</th><th>Nombre de Cliente</th>' +
   N'<th>RFC</th><th>Fax</th>' +
   N'<th>Facturación</th><th>Tipo de Saldo</th>' +
 CAST (( 
  SELECT 
  td = @cod, '', 
  td = @den, '', 
  td = @rfc, '', 
  td = @fax,'', 
  td = @polcor, '', 
  td = @debglo, '' 
 FROM Inserted 
 FOR XML PATH ('tr'), TYPE ) 
 AS NVARCHAR (MAX) ) + N' '; 
END
END
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el mensaje de error que te está dando?

Comment: Ya agregue el error en la pregunta orignal. Gracias!!!

Comment: Hola, ese error seguramente es un error de tu capa de aplicación, solo nos dice que algo falló. Prueba ejecutar el SP manualmente y copiar la salida que obtienes. Saludos